# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when install app from APK

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt

The error I describe below, occurs when:

- Install the app on a device directly from the APK.
- Download the app by Play Store

The error don´t occurs when:

- Install apk through Eclipse pressing the 'run' button

> ```
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.MainActivity}:
> ```
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.MainActivity
>
> ```
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1998)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.MainActivity
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1056)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1989)
> ... 11 more
> ```

To export the APk I do as always, from "Use the Export Wizard to export and sign an APK"

Any idea because it occurs from the APK but not directly from eclipse?

The above error is generated by me. But reports of users are somewhat different:

User1:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "my.package.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[zip file
>   "/data/app/my.package-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.package-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

User2:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "my.package.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/my.package-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.package-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Manifest:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> package="my.package"
> android:versionCode="12"
> android:versionName="2.3" >
>
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="9"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/motion"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:largeHeap="true" 
>     android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"  >
>
>
>     <activity
>         android:name="my.package.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>      <activity android:name="my.package.AlarmsListActivity" 
>                android:theme="@style/dialogTheme"/>
>      <activity android:name="my.package.ImagenesActivity"/>         
>      <activity android:name="my.package.EndActivity" />  
>
>
> </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

I use the following libraries in MainActivity

[image]

Comment: I think you use proguard when prepare release apk.

Comment: if you use any sdks or library and if you using proguard you have to use  " -keep " to proguard .

Comment: Please Show your manifest file code.

Comment: I'm not using Proguard unless eclipse do it automatically. It is the first time I hear the word Proguard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[zip file "/data/app/my.package-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.package-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

***Solution:***

You have added library project as a reference to your project and also may be you have added jar files for `ChartView` and `support-v7` in your `libs` folder and also as a `Add External Jars`. So you have to enable both checkboxes for `android-support-v7.jar` file and for `chartview jar` file in `order and export menu`.

The path for it is,

```
Project - Right Click - Properties - Java Build Path - Order and Export Menu.
```

Finally you need to clean and run your project.

Comment: Having the same issue with Android Studio and for versions below  5.0, could you please help.