# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when install app from Google play

Tags: android, android-studio, classnotfoundexception

Actualy I'm developing and application with the following configuration:

```
minSDK= API 16
TargetSDK = API 21
```

and I have the same erro described on [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when install app from APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739834/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-when-install-app-from-apk) except that this problem was found when making the installation through Google Play. But this issue was resolved on eclipse IDE, and I don't found the solution for android studio. Is possible apply the same solution for Android Studio IDE?

Comment: Is the solution present there no good for you.

Comment: @Maverick, any suggestion?

Comment: i can't say anything about android studio as i dont use it. But the problem here seems to be with your libraries section. The code is fine. You should check your java build path section.