# Android APK does not contain MainActivity class

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build, dex

I have the exact same issue as the following: [dex file does not contain MainActivity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245439/dex-file-does-not-contain-mainactivity-class/56851913#56851913)

Since I cant ask for extra help on that thread I have to recreate one.

My comment:
"I still have the same issue. Its an copy older Cordova project (which I recently updated for one client, without any issues). I renamed the project; changed up some resource files, and now I keep getting the same issue as the initial thread creator. I tried all the suggestions, None seem to work for me. Any clues on what is happening, would I need to change around more then just the name and bundle id's. The main activity is linked to the correct name, but when the APK is build and I go open the apk in android studio, it does not show me the folder for the app 'name' where the mainactivity should be.

I do not have the 'gen' folder. So I cannot remove that, unless these are special folders you can only see at some point?"

Im getting fairly frustrated, I checked all the project files for the build that is not working and a working build [2]. I tried to reproduce the issue with the old build, but that one just seems to work. If I make an exact copy of that build, change up the bundle id's [1]. It just doesnt work.

[1][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJVy7.jpg

**EDIT:** The fix that worked for me was: Changing the bundle ID; I assume that the name contained something ilegal? The thing I changed in the bundle id was: 'com.*companyname*.cvs' The thing that broke it was the 'cvs'. As soon as I renamed it, and reproduced the steps I did before, it fixed it.

Comment: Stupid, but in some cases i also get this error. Try to run cordova rebuild ( or build if you wish ) then open Android project and try to launch. If doesn't help - Clean project - Rebuild

Comment: @Cheese See my Edit. With me it was an issue with bundle id naming... No good explanation for how or what. But that solved it for me.

Comment: Interesting, would be glad to hear why is that. Maybe because CVS is a registered app name already?